# Clear Select value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, select

I have a select input where I have to clear the selected value. Here even If if set **valueS = null** Select is still showing last selected value. When I on the button to clear the selected value from Select. How to achieve it?

```
    <select (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="valueS">
        <option value="null" >Add filter</option>
        <option value="Hi">Hi</option>
        <option value="Hey">Hey</option>
        <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
    </select>
<button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
```

in `Component`:

```
clear() {
    this.valueS = null
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the use-case: each time you select any value, you want to set the selection to null? Why? You say you have a button to clear the selected value, but I see no button in the posted code.

Comment: The code was just a reference to what I'm trying to achieve. However Code Updated.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7Ut8N8CHirbBmLb5SxHc?p=preview. Post a plunkr reproducing the issue.

Comment: @JBNizet Check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wbJJQjzYRvrsSXUh8ahH?p=preview

Comment: This Works http://plnkr.co/edit/c2BDXrDLSi0BWfxIOcmN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using: `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`
and `[(ngModel)]="valueS"` both together, Check your `console` you are getting **error**. So remove `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`.

Mainly we use `(ngModelChange)` for onchange you want to do something and still you want to do then try something like this:

```
 <select name="s" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [ngModel]="valueS">
```

and

```
 onChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
    ...
}
```

> See the difference between `[(ngModel)]` and `[ngModel]` with `(ngModelChange)`

Hope this will work.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help but this -> http://plnkr.co/edit/c2BDXrDLSi0BWfxIOcmN?p=preview works....

Comment: It would be great if you used this link in an answer to your own question and accepted it, I've been after a solution for this for quite some time and this is the only thing that worked